# SVC's predict_proba and decision_function speed difference

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Does predict_proba have any dependency on decision_function under the hood of sklearn for SVC?

I trained a SVC model with probability set to True, when performing inference on a single data entry x.shape = (1, N_features), the time requires to get result from model.decision_function(x) is much slower than model.predict_proba(x). I assume predict_proba would first call decision_function and then calculate the calibrated probability, why would it run faster than decision_function. Also when computing decision_function, it also runs out memory with large dataset and large class number, which is not the case for predict_proba.

Are there some fundamental differences on how these two methods are implemented?

```py
model = SVC(probability=True)

#class_num = 150, data_train.shape = (3000, 500)
model.fit(data_train, label_train) 

start_time = time()
model.predict_proba(data_test[0].reshape(1, -1))
inference_time = (time() - start_time) # takes 0.002 seconds

start_time = time()
model.decision_function(data_test[0].reshape(1, -1))
inference_time = (time() - start_time) # takes 0.15 seconds
```

I expect the predict_proba to be slower than decision_function, however the result is the opposite.